# eShopOnContainers-Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy eShopOncontainers to AKS with the help of eShopOncontainers-wiki-github.

I don't know where/how to run the below command. They mentioned "Deploy Public Images From DockerHub" for windows use below command.

.\deploy-all.ps1 -externalDns aks -aksName  -aksRg  -imageTag linux-dev -useMesh $false

I've tried both Azure cli and windows powershell, the below error is showing

The term '.\deploy-all.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

Comment: You need to check that the file exist at the repo level

Comment: Yes it's there in deploy/k8s/helm folder. Can you tell me where I have to run this command..\deploy-all.ps1 -externalDns aks -aksName -aksRg -imageTag linux-dev -useMesh $false. Can you edit me with the sample information for the above command

Comment: Yeah, its here `https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/deploy/k8s/helm`, so you should clone that repo on your computer and then cd that directory and run the `.\deploy-all.ps1 -externalDns aks -aksName <aks-cluster-name> -aksRg <resource-group-name> -imageTag linux-dev -useMesh $false` from Powershell